How to use .env in python
I have been trying to use a .env to hold my critical API key.  When accessing the .env my code fails but using direct it succeeds.  I want to use the .env in my code.  What is wrong with my syntax? Please suggest a working model. The error I receive when using the .env is:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

My .env contains:
headers={
'x-api-key':"sLEW68I3862.......75NKanjI"
}  

My Python script:
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values 
import os

load_dotenv()

url="https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/quote"

# Script fails when I retrieve the header/API this way

# headers = os.getenv('headers')
# print(f'headers is: {headers}')

# Script works when using this: API not complete for security reasons

headers={
'x-api-key': "sLEW68I38624..........75NKanjI"
}
print(f'headers is: {headers}')

ticker_List = ("AAPL", "AMZN", "F", "T")

for ticker in ticker_List:

    querystring = {"symbols": ticker}

    response = requests.request("GET", url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)
    print("________________")
    print()


Please edit and include a complete Python traceback in your question, because without it your question is unanswerable.

try using python package python-dotenv
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Two problems.
First:
**#My .env contains:**
headers={
'x-api-key':"sLEW68I3862.......75NKanjI"
}  


.env files should not look like that. They should be like:
MYAPP_API_KEY="sLEW68I3862.......75NKanjI"
MYAPP_USER="myuser"
MYAPP_PASSWORD="mypassword"

...etc. The details are because an env file should more or less be validly executable shell script (on Linux-like platforms) and that's how you declare an environment variable in a shell. All caps is the preferred style but it technically doesn't matter.
Second:
os.getenv doesn't return a dict like that. Given an environment variable name, it returns either the value or None. You would use it like this in your example (using the env file written in the way I showed you above):
from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values 
import os

load_dotenv()

url = "https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/quote"

API_KEY = os.getenv("MYAPP_API_KEY")

if not API_KEY:
    raise SystemExit("MYAPP_API_KEY not provided, exiting!")


headers = {'x-api-key': API_KEY}

print(f'headers is: {headers}')


Thank you for this reply.  It has solved my problem and I also appreciate the formatting suggestions.
